# Can/Should a Model class in Android extend an Observable

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I am new to android development, so I wanted to know weather having a **model implementing an observable** is good practice or would [this](http://xkcd.com/292/) happen.

In my case my model is not a database model but a state of a server. I have the following classes

- **MainActivity** - The main stuff
- **FragmentInfo** - A Fragment View which holds a textbox
- **ModelServerStatus** - A simple class that holds a boolean variable and a few helpfull function to set/get variables.
- **ThreadCheckServerStatus** - The thread that connects to the server over UDP and does write/read. This thread knows about `ModelServerStatus` and will update `ModelServerStatus` by using setStatus. This thread is always running and sleeps for say 5 seconds.

Should I extend `Observable` on `ModelServerStatus` and call notify every time `ModelServerStatus.setStatus(true/false)` is run. This way the `MainActivity` can be the `Observer` and update `FragmentInfo.textView`.

A very basic `ModelServerStatus.setStatus()` implementation

```
public void setStatus(boolean newStatus)
{
    // See if the value of the server has changed
    if (hasStatusChanged(newStatus))
    {
         //Observer Notify
         setChanged();
         notifyObserver();
    }
}
```

My thinking behind this:

> The Model will notify the Controller to update the view

or

> The ModelServerStatus will Notify MainActivity to update the FragmentInfo

I did also think about

> The Controller will check the Model for updates, and update the View if required.

But that sounds wrong.

**The question really is, What would be the best implementation of this task!**

Thoughts? thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

I think what I would do in this case, is have a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) running in the background. That will keep state of the server. Initialize it as false. You connect to the server, when that is successful set it as true. Poll it as you need, set it to false when the server is not available anymore.

The [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) should fire a [broadcast](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) when the status changes from true to false or vice versa.

In the Activity (or Fragment) you can [register](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for the [broadcast](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) in onResume(). Unregister the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in onPause().

Whenever your Service detects a change, your UI components will get a broadcast.

**WARNING**

Doing network polling will make your users very, **very** grumpy. Most users will uninstall your App for such behaviour.

Comment: Awesome this can be done in a service +1, but I am not sure how this is better or worse than my model. Also I only want it to poll only when the app is running, and not when its paused,

Comment: You can always stop the service on pause. And start it on resume. Your model would be fine I am sure. But the generally accepted method for dealing with long term networking events is through a service. The broadcast method of communication works nicely in this case, though you could just as easily create a direct communication system.